# Django : ORM objects come with nothing in _meta.local_fields

Tags: python, django

[python 2.6 - django 1.1.1]

Hello.

I'm writing a custom serializer for my django application.

All the objects that I use are proxy objects derived from django model classes and implement special members that I must serialize (hence the custom serializer).

So I've begun to implement a new abstract serializer that inherits `django.core.serialiazer.base.Serializer` and redifines the `serialize(...)` method. I've also begun a python concrete serializer (child-class of my own base Serializer), needed for custom construction of the dict.

Problem is, when my queryset comes into the serialize() method, each individual `obj` in it has an empty list (`[]`) for `obj._meta.local_fields`. As a consequence, my serialized python dicts are almost empty (apart from primary key & model), because I rely on this list.

I can't seem to find where this field is inited. I don't understand, also, why _meta.local_fields is inconsistent when I use my serializer and not when I use django's serializer (i pass the same querysets of proxy objects).

Thanks.

**EDIT:** i thought maybe some `__init__` code somewhere in the django packages had an effect, but I can't find anything in that direction, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that proxy objects don't have local_fields set, which would be logical. I've just found something in the existing code (exploiting the django python serializer) that works around the lack of local_fields...

I think my question is void :-/